# MySQL Join query with not condition still includes the undesired results

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two tables. One with stock information and one with user choice information. I am trying to query my db and have a set of results from this query where information on the user choice table is omitted from the results of the stock information.

Yet in attempting to roll this query out and refine it I have trimmed it down from one to many results, way more than there should have been, to now the correct results but its still giving me the equivlant of just doing a regular simple select without the conditions. Including the result(s) I don't want to appear. From this query I should have all but 2 results for this test, but those 2 still show with the rest. I think Im on the right track with this query but something somewhere I am missing something.

Can someone explain to me how I did this wrong?

```
select distinct 
stock.teamType, 
stock.teamName, 
stock.leagueType
from teamNames stock
left join teams user on stock.teamName not in (user.teamName)
where user.membID = 20 and stock.leagueType = 'nfl'
```

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: Try replacing `left join teams user on stock.teamName not in (user.teamName)` with `LEFT JOIN teams user ON stock.teamName != user.teamName`.

Comment: p.s. Your problem's description is awful. It's hardly to understand what your goal is.

Comment: Yea, Im not that great and verbalizing myself in that way. Very sorry, but do thank you for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select distinct  stock.teamType,  stock.teamName,  stock.leagueType 
from teamNames stock
left join teams on stock.teamname = teams.teamname
and teams.membid = 20
where teams.teamname is null
and leaguetype = 'nfl'
```

Comment: forgot about the `is null` concept. good call, that gave me exactly what I wanted.